# How to use file_get_contents in php ? , my code does not work

Tags: php

this piece of code is in a php file, it does not create or open a file

```
<?php

function file_stuff(){
    $text = "hello world";
    file_put_contents("myFirst.txt","$text");
    $text1 = file_get_contents("myFirst.txt");
    print "$text1";
}

# main program
file_stuff();

?>
```

Comment: Surely you must be getting an error?

Comment: check it again it does work perfectly.

Comment: you do know you don't have to wrap your php string variables in quotes right? In fact you generally want to avoid doing so unless they are in the middle of a static text string

Comment: Sandaruwan Wijesiriwardana, remember to mark as "answer" the answer you think is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) returns a boolean `false` on error, so you should test for that:

```
if(file_put_contents("myFirst.txt", $text) !== false)
{
    $text1 = file_get_contents("myFirst.txt");
    print $text1;
}
else
{
    print "Failed to write to file";
}
```

You probably don't have permission to write to the current directory.

Side note: you don't need to keep wrapping variables in quotes, just use the variable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works correctly, it shows me "Hello world".

Check the permissions on the directory where you run the script.

Comment: Yep, now it's working. There was a problem with the permissions on the directory. Now it let me read and write files. thank you so much......

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $toPut = "Hello World";
    file_put_contents("./myTextFile.txt", $toPut);

    $myTextFile = file_get_contents("./myTextFile.txt");
    echo $myTextFile;

?>
```

If that code doesn't work, you may be having permission errors.

Try using [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to set the file's permission after it has been written, like this:

```
chmod(0755, "./myTextFile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`allow_url_fopen = On`

made above change in your php.ini file and all will work fine.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is for remote files, OP has a local file.

Answer (score 0):

The Piece is supposed to work fine. In My Computer it works just fine.
Here are check points:

1. [Turn on errors and warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) Also see [here](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/)
2. Check permissions in directory you are trying to write